# Why I am getting this exception, what I am doing wrong here

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Failed to bounce to type

```
W/System.err:
at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)

caused by : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class hi.example.com.hi.DataModel] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method.
```

even if i use single string constructor in my DataModel class , i get one string value at a time in the constructor,, why this happening ,, please someone help me ..

```
 here is my json file
   {  
      "messages": {
        "matt__walk": {
          "Username": "matt__walk",
          "imageurl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0",
          "text": "hii"
             }
         }
   }
```

DataModel class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class DataModel {
    private String Username;
    private String imageurl;
    private String text;

    public DataModel(){
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageurl;
    }
}
```

MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Menu menu;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Firebase ref;
    private String res;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, MessageViewHolder>    mFirebaseAdapter;

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mViews;
        CircleImageView img;
        TextView name,data;
        public MessageViewHolder(View views) {
            super(views);
            mViews = views;
        }

        public void setText(String Name) {
            TextView name = (TextView) mViews.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            name.setText(Name);
        }

        public void setData(String Data) {
            TextView data = (TextView) mViews.findViewById(R.id.datas);
            data.setText(Data);
        }

        public void setImage(Context cnt, String imageUrl) {
            CircleImageView img = (CircleImageView) mViews.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Picasso.with(cnt).load(imageUrl).into(img);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ref = new Firebase("https://hi-34.firebaseio.com/messages/matt__walk");
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, MessageViewHolder>(
                DataModel.class,
                R.layout.rowplaces,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                ref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, DataModel dataModel, int i) {


                        messageViewHolder.setText(dataModel.getUsername());
                        messageViewHolder.setData(dataModel.getText());
                 messageViewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),dataModel.getImageUrl());


            }
        };
        mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
    int lastVisiblePosition =    layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't get any help without showing your code so put it up somewhere so people can see what you're doing/trying.

Comment: `ref = new Firebase("URL here");` Please post the data at that URL (as text, no screenshot), which you can export from your Firebase dashboard.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen now please tell me why i am getting that exception .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycler views (and list views) show lists of items. The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is made to populate such a list of items.

If you add a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` on a node, it will try to add the nodes **under that node** to the recycler view. So in your case that means that it tries to add `Username`, `imageurl` and `text` to the list. That doesn't seem to be what you have in mind. To solve this problem, you'll need to make the adapter listen one level higher in the tree:

```
ref = new Firebase("https://hi-34.firebaseio.com/messages");
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, MessageViewHolder>(
        DataModel.class,
        R.layout.rowplaces,
        MessageViewHolder.class,
        ref
) {
```

With that, it will call `populateViewHolder` for each child of `messages`, the first/only one of which is `matt__walk`.

The second problem is that you have a mismatch between the casing of the property names in your JSON and the corresponding getters in your Java class.

If use:

```
public class DataModel {
    private String username;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String text;

    public DataModel(){
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageurl;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
matt__walk": {
    "username": "matt__walk",
    "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0",
    "text": "hii"
}
```

Comment: yeah its finally work,,,a big thanks to Frank you really save my day man ,,i was stucked from three days ,now it finally solved my problem,,one last question , how can i pick a particular node if parent node "message" have number of nodes. ,.. Should i use List for that or what ?